# How can I adjust a whole-house ventilation bathroom exhaust timer?

Tags: hvac, timer, exhaust

We have a home built in 2008 in west-central Minnesota. As a cost-saving (I perceive it as such, and may be mistaken) measure to fulfill air quality and venting code, the builder set up an upstairs bathroom's exhaust fan to run on a timer - something like 45mins of every hour. It's apparently designed to replace the entire house's air volume once each day.

The switch can also be flipped up to run the fan on demand, and turns the fan off when flipped down. I'm not sure if the timer has any relation to whether the switch is on or off, though.

I've been thinking of either adjusting the timer so it runs less frequently, or disabling it  entirely (with an easy option to re-enable it).

Any thoughts? What should I look for? Is there a timer at the fan, or is this something a little more intricate at the switch? Would this be a two-way switch with one end controlled by the timer?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the vent:  take the cover off and examine it for mechanisms, part numbers, etc. that you can see without taking it apart further.  Take photos and post it.

Likewise, take the trim plate off the switches and see if there's anything interesting or whether it's just a plain switch like any other.

I installed a timer for the bathroom fan that's just a fancy switch, and it's quite obvious because it has time buttons and lights at the switch.  If your behavior is independent of the switch position it needs a power supply separate from the switch, and the switch may be wired funny even if it is a plain switch.

I'm guessing it's built into the fan unit.  IAC, it would have to accessible somewhere, not invisibly sealed up in the wall.  So "it" is probably either at one end or the other.